# Add the same layout to one container android

Tags: java, android

I want to add the same layout to the same layout in code:

```
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.contactLayout);
for (Info info : contact.getInfo()) {
    View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_contact_header, null);
    TextView headerText = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.contactHeader);
    headerText.setText(info.getSection());
    container.addView(headerText);
    for (Row row : info.getRows()) {
        View item = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_kontakt_oss, null);
        TextView itemHeader = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.itemHeader);
        TextView itemValue = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.itemValue);
        ImageView imageIcon = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.imageIcon);
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) item.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        itemHeader.setText(row.getHeader());
        itemValue.setText(row.getDetails());
        imageIcon.setImageResource(getDrawableForItem(row.getActionType()));
            relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            });
            container.addView(item);
        }
    }
```

but I get error:`java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`

Any ideas how can I solve this?

Comment: 2 things: 1. which line does this error point to? 2. There's 99% chance that you should be doing this with `RecyclerView` instead of your `LinearLayout`.

Comment: line with error:  container.addView(headerText);

Comment: Does your container LinearLayout have a view in it already? I just created a sample app with similar code, and I have no errors. the headers and items are added just fine into the LinearLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add a view that is already a child of another view. headerText is a child of 'header' in your case.
You can add a view after you inflated it as a whole.

```
container.addView(header);
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

`getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_contact_header, null)`

and

`getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_kontakt_oss, container, false);`

with

`getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_contact_header, container, false)
getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_kontakt_oss, container, false)`